# PHP Switch case default wont work?

Tags: php, html, switch-statement, case, default

Hi Stackoverflow members!

**Problem**
Main file:

```
<?php
    $privileges = $_SESSION['privileges'];
    switch ($privileges) {
        case "admin":
            echo '';
            break;
        case "user":
            echo '';
            break;
        default:
            header("location: nologon.php");
    }
?>
```

"head.php" file:

```
<?php
error_reporting(0);
include('connect.php');
session_start();
?>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <!--<?php include('./assets/js/block_mouse.min.js') ?>
    <?php include('./assets/js/block_ctrl.min.js') ?>-->
    <link href="assets/img/soccer.ico" rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="./assets/css/stylesheet.css">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="./assets/js/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="./assets/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>
```

The server wont redirect clients to the "nologon.php" page when they aren't logged in. All the other pages and PHP codes works perfectly, but this don't?
Screenshots:
Main file:

```
http://gyazo.com/cc7836bfddaceff4d1f4c27cbb05d67e
```

head.php file:

```
http://gyazo.com/b1f67ad03081e4e958b2d673ac7e3316
```

- Thanks in advance!

Comment: `header("location: nologon.php"); exit;`

Comment: Okay now people dosen't load the page (In the default case), but it's still not redirecting people to the page i want, which is "nologon.php". I can't seem to find the logic in this case.

Comment: Have you tested if the switch calls the default when the user is not logged in? Like putting a `var_dump` or `echo` there just to see if all is good?

Comment: It shouldn't really make a difference in this case, but try change the double quotes to single quotes for the header location

Comment: Yes, I've tried that, Mikolaj.

Comment: @ErwinBolwidt What're you talking about?

Comment: @Mikolaj I tried, still nothing.

Comment: Have you tried adding the full URL to the Location: header? You should also try replacing the header statement to just a simple echo or die to check if the code is executed properly. Then you can determine whether the issue lies with the header you are trying to send or the logic.

Comment: @shrmn Yes, already tried that.

Answer (score 0):

Not totally sure, but I think `location:` needs to be `Location:`

Also, just in case:

> Remember that header() must be called before any actual output is
>   sent, either by normal HTML tags, blank lines in a file, or from PHP.
>   It is a very common error to read code with include, or require,
>   functions, or another file access function, and have spaces or empty
>   lines that are output before header() is called. The same problem
>   exists when using a single PHP/HTML file.

(From [php.net](http://php.net/manual/en/function.header.php))

Also, `exit;`, like `header('Location: nologin.php'); exit;`

---

After looking at your screenshot(s), put all this at the beggining of your head.php file (move it around however you want, but the `header` needs to be *before* the `<head>` tag that is in head.php) like *after* `session_start();`:

```
<?php
    include 'head.php';

    $privileges = $_SESSION['privileges'];
    switch ($privileges) {
        case "admin":
            echo '';
            break;
        case "user":
            echo '';
            break;
        default:
            header("location: nologon.php");
            exit;
    }
?>
<html>
...
```

Comment: I've tried to change "header("location: nologon.php");" to "header("Location: nologon.php");". Still nothing.

Comment: @bilbodog Ok, is your `header` called before any other output? I also added to my answer.

Comment: And then a screenshot of the head.php file if you want to know what's in there: http://gyazo.com/bb310bbfb76b2f0c126b6eb10dc3dd97

Comment: @bilbodog Ok, try putting your whole switch statement above all the html.

Comment: If I do that, then the "session_start();" command and my defines variables wont be loaded. Then it will just do the default case even if it is users or admins reaching the page.

The "head.php" is the file that loads the connection, session_start, styles and what so ever.

Comment: Then put ALL of that before the `<html>`.

Comment: I've tried it anyways and gives me this warning: "Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at /home/xxx/public_html/product.php:3) in /home/xxx/public_html/product.php on line 13"

Comment: I tried put all the PHP stuff before the <html> and still nothing happens when supposed in the default case.

Comment: please replace index.php with nologon.php and let us know if you are able to see a page??

Comment: @bilbodog Maybe we need to see what head.php is doing. Care to put some examples in your question of that code?

Comment: @bilbodog, what is the value of $_SESSION['privileges'] ?

Comment: @bilbodog ok, i see what the problem is here and i put it in my answer. but you need to have the `header` *before* the `<head>` tag for sure.

Comment: check my answer's last line for solution. Add that at the top of your code.

Comment: @AshutoshNigam The only variables possible is:
http://gyazo.com/b29b5bfc5c4b9e4d72ddd290b97bdba7
and then nothing.

Comment: @Mikolaj It's not required. I already tried and it still dosen't work if I do that anyways.

Comment: @bilbodog there can be null also one of the option, I am trying to take care of that.

Comment: @AshutoshNigam I've tried upload my website to www.hostinger.com and there all my coding works fine without ANY problems.

But why dosen't it work on my server provider's system, where I'm hosting my .dk domain and my server?

Answer (score 0):

Updated code

```
  <?php
    if(isset($_SESSION['privileges'])
        $privileges = $_SESSION['privileges'];
    else 
         header("location: ./nologon.php");

    switch ($privileges) {
        case "admin":
            echo '';
            break;
        case "user":
            echo '';
            break;
        default:
            header("location: nologon.php");
    }
?>
```

History:
if the nologin.php is in same folder then use as follows:

```
header("location: ./nologon.php");
```

It would be good to check isset for the session var.

**If nologon.php is not in website's root folder then please move it there.**

AS your seesion variable is not set please use following code:

```
if(!isset($_SESSION['privileges']) header("location: nologon.php');
```

Comment: It should not make a difference if it is in the same directory.

Comment: Already tried that for being sure, but dosen't work anyways. :)

Comment: echo the value of $_SESSION('privileges') and share plz... also let me know if the file is in same folder as the index.php?

Comment: try to run this command and see if it returns the desired page?? yoursitename/nologon.php

Comment: The main file and the file I want it to redirect is in the same folder.

Comment: The variable is not set, when users don't log in and that's why it wont react on the 2 cases and then I need the default case to react and just redirect them to the "nologon.php" page.

Comment: I've already tried to make a big fat <h1></h1> where is shows the value of $_SESSION['privileges'] and it brings up values when people are logged in and it dosen't shows any values when people are not logged in, which is exactly as I wanted it too. Just the default case that's messing with my mind right now.

Comment: Please check the last line in my answer posted.

Comment: It should be the first line in your page.

Answer (score 0):

I think you have something wrong on session data because it work fine, anyway
try add `echo` before it

```
echo header("Location: nologon.php");
```

Comment: When I log in, everything is shown correctly without problems, so I think it works. Just the default case that's messing with my mind.

Comment: Tried that, still gets nothing.

Comment: @bilbodog - Make sure `nologon.php` if its in **root** or not. I tried it, there is nothing wrong!

Comment: Its where it needs to be. :)

Comment: I've tried on www.hostinger.com and there it's working fine aswell. What can the issue be then?